# Why directory is not getting added inside apache2 web server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

My apache2 site is configured as i am able to see the content i wrote inside index.html:

[image]

Now i wanted to add directory structure so inside conf file i made changes as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@crap.com
    ServerName share.com
    ServerAlias www.crap.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crap.com/public_html
    Alias /vagrant /home/vagrant/services
    <Directory "/home/vagrant/services">
          Options None
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
   </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

but on the webserver i dont see any directory structure appearing.
So, please suggest why am i not able to add directory structure on the page and how can it be resolved?
When i try to access 192.168.10.10/vagrant i get following window:

[image]

following are the result of ls -l:
[image]

Comment: can you share the screenshot when you access http://192.168.10.10/vagrant?

Comment: Replace this `Options None`  to `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`  and then check.

Comment: @SahilGulati i have replaced Options as you told and have adde the screenshot also

Comment: Okay! i will provide you the config.

Comment: I have updated the configuration. Please check and let me know. If it does not work. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this configuration of apache. Hope it works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@crap.com
    ServerName share.com
    ServerAlias www.crap.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crap.com/public_html
    Alias /vagrant /home/vagrant/services
    <Directory "/home/vagrant/services">
          Require all granted
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I did as told but still problem is not resoved. Showing same mesage as forbidden.

Comment: @Learner please check whether that path exists or not? Do one thing change your path to /home

Comment: yes changing to /home worked..but how can i have the acess to subdirectories inside vagrant now. It does not show anything inside vagrant directory.

Comment: Okay run this command. `cd /home/vagrant && chmod 777 * -R` there could be reason that your current user does not have permission. Change mode for now, after get it done you can change according to your need

Comment: tried cd /home/vagrant && chmod 777 * -R but got error as cannot acces *:no such file exist hence I navigated to the folder cd /home/vagrant/services and there passed "chmod -R 777",only want services folder and then on the browser i reloaded but it did not worked

Comment: Navigate to /home/vagrant. And hit `ls -l`command and please share result

Comment: Strange.. everythings is looking fine... change path to /home/vagrant/services/ restart apache and try again or navigate to the above path and hit pwd command then copy path to you apache config... do chmod 777 * -R in services folder also

Comment: it seems like subfolders are not under root rather are in vagrant as a root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136076/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-learner).